# how can i change order of div by jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this container:

```
<div id="mycontainer" class="main">
  <div class="content">Content here</div>
  <div class="title">title here</div>
</div>
```

I clone the div using jquery and append it to another div:

```
var $cloneBrick = $this.clone().prop("id", "mycontainerNEW");
$("#infopane").append($cloneBrick);
```

On the mainpage where I fetch the container it shows title before content. If I clone it and add it to the other div it shows title after the content.

I can not change the mainpage! I have to reorder it in the cloned element using jquery or css.

What is the best way to change the order of the divs?

** Edit ** This is the css code in main page for the title:

```
.mainpage .main .title {
    display: block;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    background: rgba(227, 227, 227, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

If the title is part of mainpage it will be set by top=0 left=0 to be displayed as a head of the container. But i cloned it outside of mainpage

**Edit** Snippet based on provided code:

```js
var $cloneBrick = $("#mycontainer").clone().prop("id", "mycontainerNEW");
$("#infopane").append($cloneBrick);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mycontainer" class="main">
  <div class="content">Content here</div>
  <div class="title">title here</div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div id="infopane">

</div>
```

Comment: why not change it with CSS by either using the `order` property or a flex or grid layout with a reverse direction?

Comment: `$cloneBrick.append($cloneBrick.find('.content'))`

Comment: I've added a snippet based on the code you've provided.   As you can see, given only the code provided, it does not do what you say - the order is preserved.   "*On the mainpage where I fetch the container it shows title before content*" - as the div order is content then title, as it is showing title then content, then this will have either been changed via js or, more likely, had some CSS applied (similar to @tacoshy comment above) - ie the css is already applied to the existing element.  You need to change the css rule (or add a new one) so that it also applies to your new content.

Comment: Without a [mcve] (or even, dare I say it, a screenshot of the result) it's hard to tell what "*shows before*" means - it could be a simple rule `.content { float:right }` (or a more specific `#mycontainer .content { float:right }` so not applied to your new container).  Which would put the "title before content":  https://jsfiddle.net/kgoh4ju8/

Comment: Each div is a full line so content comes before title but title needs to become first in order.

Comment: From your css, `position: absolute;` sets the position of the `title` - so I would assume there's an equivalent css for the `content`.   The css rule will **only apply** to your new/cloned content if `#infopane` is inside `.mainpage`.   Please [edit] the question to provide a *complete* sample (the additional css info a good first step, but not complete).

Answer (score 0):

You can just set css to the cloned version as it goes in the snippet,
display the cloned element as `flex`, and set flex direction to `reverse`,

```js
var $cloneBrick = $("#mycontainer").clone().prop("id", "mycontainerNEW");
$("#infopane").append($cloneBrick);
```

```css
 #mycontainerNEW {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mycontainer" class="main">
  <div class="content">Content here</div>
  <div class="title">title here</div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div id="infopane">

</div>
```